# How to make this (pbmove)= picturebox follow my mouse

Tags: c#

Code:

```
    private void pbMove_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (pbMove.Top > Cursor.Position.Y)
        {
            pbMove.Top--;
        }

        if (pbMove.Top < Cursor.Position.Y)
        {
            pbMove.Top++;
        }

        if (pbMove.Left > Cursor.Position.X)
        {
            pbMove.Left++;
        }

        if (pbMove.Left < Cursor.Position.X)
        {
            pbMove.Left--;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You din't ask a question but your code speaks for itself..

Note that `Cursor.Position` is in screen coordiantes and `pbMove.xxx` in the coodinates of its `Parent`, maybe the form. Look into [`PointToScreen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoscreen%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`PointToClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) !

Replace

```
if (pbMove.Top > Cursor.Position.Y)
```

with

```
if (pbMove.PointToScreen(pbMove.Location).Top > Cursor.Position.Y)
```

etc..

Also note that this will **lag** behind the mouse, as many `MouseMove` events will have covered a distance greater than 1. To make the control 'stick' to you mouse simply set the `Location` to the difference to the `Location` it had on `MouseDown`! (Yopu will need to store that `Point`!)

Also note that you probably should test for the Left Button to be pressed. Here is working example:

```
Point mDown = Point.Empty;

private void pbMove_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{  mDown = e.Location;  }

private void pbMove_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        Size sz = new Size(mDown.X - e.X, mDown.Y - e.Y);
        pbMove.Location = Point.Subtract(pbMove.Location, sz);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's right, sorry. Exchange Top and Left for Y and X!

Answer (score 0):

I remember using the DragMove() method inside the MouseDown event handler to do something similar. See if this helps

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.window.dragmove(VS.85).aspx

Comment: i dont want to drag it it just has to follow the mouse but thx anyway:)

Comment: Well that __is__ dragging. Note that it __doesn't__ start a drag&drop operation.. But it works only for windows, I think and  is not part of `winforms` anyway..

Answer (score -1):

Here's the absolute best code I've ever written for this. It's using Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "Rx-WinForms").

First we need to know when the mouse downs, moves and ups occur.

```
        var downs =
            Observable
                .FromEventPattern<MouseEventHandler, MouseEventArgs>(
                    h => pbMove.MouseDown += h, h => pbMove.MouseDown -= h)
                .Select(x => x.EventArgs);

        var moves =
            Observable
                .FromEventPattern<MouseEventHandler, MouseEventArgs>(
                    h => pbMove.MouseMove += h, h => pbMove.MouseMove -= h)
                .Select(x => x.EventArgs);

        var ups =
            Observable
                .FromEventPattern<MouseEventHandler, MouseEventArgs>(
                    h => pbMove.MouseUp += h, h => pbMove.MouseUp -= h)
                .Select(x => x.EventArgs);
```

Next we need to know what the mouse delta position is from the start of a down, while the mouse moves, until the mouse goes up.

```
        var deltas = from down in downs
                     from move in moves.TakeUntil(ups)
                     select new Point()
                     {
                        X = move.X - down.X,
                        Y = move.Y - down.Y
                     };
```

Finally we can use these deltas to update the position of the picture box.

```
        var subscription =
                deltas
                    .Subscribe(d =>
                        pbMove.SetBounds(
                            pbMove.Location.X + d.X,
                            pbMove.Location.Y + d.Y,
                            0, 0, BoundsSpecified.Location));
```

This code works and is very neat.

To turn off the drag/move function just call `.Dispose()` on `subscription`.